# Different times for call of fajr prayer on consecutive days

Tags: salat

Yesterday here in a mosque the call for fajr was given at 4:50 am and today it was given at 4:35 am.

How is it decided that 15 mins is to be changed on a single day when there were no time pieces during prophets time? I live in India.

Comment: Prayer call can basically be at any time. It depends only on local costums. Some locations apply the sunnah with an adhan before fajr in Ramadan and an other on time. And depending to local costums the adhan can vary.

Answer (score 2):

The time for fajr is not instantaneous but lasts for a period from dawn to just before sunrise.

> The time of the morning prayer is from the appearance of dawn, as long
>   as the sun has not risen; but when the sun rises, refrain from prayer
>
> <sub>— [Saheeh Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/222)</sub>
>
> Gabriel (عَلَيْهِ السَّلاَمُ) led me in prayer at the House (i.e. the Ka'bah) ... he
>   prayed the dawn prayer with me when food and drink become forbidden to
>   one who is keeping the fast.On the following day ... he prayed the
>   dawn prayer with me when there was a fair amount of light. Then
>   turning to me he said:  Muhammad (ﷺ), this is the time observed by the
>   prophets before you, and the time is anywhere between two times.
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/3)</sub>

Mosques usually delay it a bit in normal circumstances but bring it closer to *Saher* in Ramadhan to provide convenience to the people.

Also in normal circumstances, the time for dawn and sunrise keeps on gradually changing as the solar year progresses, but Mosques don't change time everyday and instead make a change of 15 minutes after a bunch of days.

Comment: You have not quoted the hadith, the best time for prayer is earliest times. Mecca prays in earliest time throughout the year.

Comment: @Preotdainment your statememt doesn't apply for sure for 'isha' in Ramadan

Comment: There is another hadith about delaying Isha upto midnight. No such hadith to delay fajr upto sunrise.

Comment: @user22565 Actually there is: أسفروا بالفجر فإنه أعظم للأجر  e.g. in [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/6) and [Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1105510)